# Javascript objects parsed vs created

Tags: javascript, json

What is the **practical** difference between `p` and `p2` objects here:

```
var Person = function(name) { this.Name=name; }
var p = new Person("John");

var p2 = JSON.parse('{"Name":"John"}');
```

What are the cases when I would better create `new Person()` and copy values from parsed JSON, rather than use that parsed JSON object as I would use the instance of `Person`?

PS. Let's say I got JSON string from WebSocket and I will have to parse it anyway.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The main difference is that `p` is an object, that is an instance of `Person` while `p2` is a "plain" object, that is just an instance of `Object`.

When is this difference important?

1) accessing prototype properties:

```
var Person = function(name) { this.Name=name; }
Person.prototype.getName = function () {
    return this.Name;
};

p.getName() //works fine
p2.getName() //Error since getName is not defined
```

Or:

```
console.log(p.constructor) //Person
console.log(p2.constructor) //Object
```

2) using the `instanceof` operator:

```
p instanceof Person //true
p2 instanceof Person //false
```

3) everything that has to do with inheritance

All three points can essentially be traced back to the prototype chain, that looks like this for both ways:

```
p --> Person --> Object

p2 --> Object
```

Now, since you have this constructor function I would suggest you always use it, because it can get quite messy if you mix `Person` objects with plain objects. If you really just want an object, that has a `Name` property, you would be fine in both ways, but as soon as it gets a little bit more complex, you can run into severe problems.

Comment: Thanks for extended answer.

Answer (score 6):

The difference between p and p2 is that the internal prototype of p2 is the `Object.prototype`, whereas the prototype of p is the `Person.prototype`; for the `p` you can add common methods or attributes to all `Person` objects by adding methods to the `Person.prototype`.

Thus you could have the JSON format to have fields such as "givenName", "surname" "title", and by using the `new Person` approach, you could have a method:

```
Person.prototype.getFullName = function () {
    return this.title + " " + this.givenName + " " + this.surname;
}
```

that is readily available all `Person`s derived using the constructor.

Comment: Thanks, fixed json string

Answer (score 2):

The main difference is that they have different prototype chains:

```
p.constructor ->  function (name) { this.Name=name; }
                  (the Person function)
chain: p -> Person -> Object

p2.constructor -> function Object() { [native code] } 
                  (the standard object constructor)
chain: p2 -> Object
```

If you **need the proper prototype chain** (e.g. have several methods on `Person.prototype` you want to inherit), use the `new Person()` construct. If you have a JSON String (e.g. from an ajax call), where you have all your data in (and don't need `Person` as prototype), use the `JSON.parse`, otherwise use the good ol' plain:

```
var p2 = {Name:'John'};
```

sidenote:

```
var p2 = JSON.Parse("{Name:'John'}");
```

is wrong, it needs to be:

```
var p2 = JSON.parse('{"Name":"John"}');
```

Comment: just as a sidenote: the prototype chain for `p` doesn't include `Function`.

Answer (score 1):

The parse version basically does the same with the added overhead of breaking the text up and translating it ( which isn't slow ).
I would consider it better programming using the first method, you don't want raw JSON hanging around your code :)

JSON.parse will create a very basic object from the data you give it, there's no problem with that

Using the first method allows you to define and extend the object before-hand, giving it methods and attributes allowing for better use of the data it contains.

Comment: I would appreciate emphasizing the last paragraph. Parsing a JSON string will not instantiate an object of a specific class (so not getting any prototypal methods). It will only create a basic objects with applied properties.

Answer (score 1):

Simply put, p is a Person object and p2 is just an object literal. They both have different prototypes, name the Person prototype for p and the Object prototype for p2.

The first case defines a "class" with which you create new objects, using the "class" as a constructor for the new object.

The second case creates an object literal and assigns values to the specified keys.

Answer (score 0):

your statement

```
var p2 = JSON.Parse("{Name:'John'}");
```

is just a inefficient way to do this:

```
  var p2 = {Name:'John'};
```

Comment: Yes, but let's say i got JSON string from WebSocket

Comment: @Anri that's fine... I am sure you would not code it that way... my point was to remove JSON to make the answer self-explanatory